# Notificações de comentários não chegam se a postagem é removida logo em seguida

Tags: bug, novo-recurso

A partir do 10k qualquer usuário no site [pode visualizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) perguntas e respostas removidas, no entanto aconteceu isto a pouco:

- Eu comentei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180109/3635#comment372335_180109
- O AR me comentou de volta (*2017-01-26 15:27:33Z*)
- A notificação chegou na *inbox*
- E em seguida ele deletou a postagem logo em seguida (*2017-01-26 15:27:36Z*, 3 segundos depois)
- Então a notificação sumiu da *inbox* antes mesmo que eu pudesse visualizar do que se tratava
- Então abri a *inbox* só para ter certeza, mas não aparecia, veja imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgBXg.png
- Procurei na [*réplicas*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=responses&sort=comments), mas nada apareceu também, veja a imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r76Pu.png
- Então fui olhar a aba [*atividade*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=activity&sort=comments), foi nisto que notei que um comentário meu tinha "sumido".

Penso que se o usuário tiver 10k+ deveria poder ver comentários feitos em postagens removidas:

- Na *inbox*
- Na aba *réplicas*: 
   (`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=responses&sort=comments`)
- E também poder visualizar seus próprios comentários na aba *atividade*: 
   (`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=activity`)

Ou seja é um pouco difícil acompanhar postagens deletadas, na maior parte dos casos realmente as postagens não terão utilidade, mas sempre podem haver exceções.

Comment: Mas é bug ou novo recurso? :D

Comment: "deveria poder visualizar comentários" – mas você já vê o comentário, certo? O que você gostaria é que a notificação não sumisse. Confere?

Comment: @JorgeB. está é a questão, eu não sei se é um bug. Acaso não seja então considere um pedido de novo recurso :)

Comment: @bfavaretto não confere, eu só vejo se acessar a postagem, eu editei a pergunta pois realmente faltou este detalhe. Note que as páginas `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=activity` e `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=responses&sort=comments` também não mostram os comentários feitos por mim e por outros usuários em postagens deletadas.

Comment: Guilherme o que o @bfavaretto quer dizer é que você vê os comentários na resposta apagada, não vê? Se for lá à resposta...

Comment: @JorgeB. isso sim, mas pense o quanto é complicado encontrar, a situação é eu poder ser notificado e poder procurar na página `activity` e na página `responses`.

Comment: Concordo, nem pros moderadores as listas de atividade e responses mostram comentários em publicações excluídas. Podia mesmo ser um recurso pra quem tem 10k+

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado :D, aproveitei resumi a questão aqui no meta, acho que ficou um pouco mais fácil de entender.